# Need help with Reading File Input than Calculating!

Tags: java, file-read

I am have a real hard time with this program i have to write. 
The program has to

Read in from the file

1. Name
2. Asking Price
3. Sale Price
4. Amount still owed on Mortgage

Print out AND write to a file a table that contains the following:

- Name
- Asking Price
- Mortgage Amount
- Selling Price
- Realtor Commission
- Property Taxes Net price

  Calculations:
- Realtor Commission = Selling Price * 6%
- Property Taxes = Selling Price * 10.5%
- Net Price = Asking Price - Mortgage Amount - Realtor Commission
- Total Profit / Loss = Accummulate the net prices

i have no clue how to separate the data and do separate calculations!! 
A sample data file looks like this...

```
Hopkins 250000      223000      209000
Smith   305699      299999      297500
Forrest 124999      124999      53250
Fitch   214999      202500      200000
```

There is no way i can read the data then do the calculations and then write the new data to a new file, please help!

Comment: if i can give you one piece of advice. This program seems really complicated to you, because it has lots of parts. The secret to programming success is to pretend that you will know how to do it all, and forget about almost all of the assignment, and focus on one little part. Do that, then pick another little part. So I'd try first reading the file. Don't worry about the rest. Try that, come back and ask more questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Well i already read the file for the data, the problem is I can't find a way to separate the data so i can use it for separate calculations..

Comment: My problem is that I have the data read, i just can't do anything with it...like calculate...I don't know how to process data in this format.

Comment: I'm pretty Desperete For some Help.. I've been looking at my code for the past 5hours, no joke!. Any Help is appreciated. tks

Comment: @ Anthony what sought of `file` it is? (from where you have to read)

Comment: it is a .txt file i have to read

Comment: It is so hard to get the get the file's data and separably perform the operations

Comment: @ Anthony You can also use JTable and save data data entered in object form,using `writeObject` and later retrieve data using `readObject`.

Comment: try to map your program before.Then proceed step by step.

Comment: @Anthony: Please don't remove the content of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    float netTotal = 0;
    String thisLine = null;
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt"); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inputFile.txt"));
    while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) { // while loop begins here
        String[] parts = thisLine.split("[\\t\\n\\r ]+");
        int askingPrice = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); 
        int salePrice = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        int amountOwed = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
        float commission = salePrice * 0.06;
        float tax = salePrice * 0.105;
        float netPrice = askingPrice - amountOwed - commission;
        netTotal += netPrice;

        out.write((parts[0] + "\t").getBytes());       //name
        out.write((askingPrice + "\t").getBytes());    //asking price
        out.write((amountOwed + "\t").getBytes());     //mortgage amount
        out.write((salePrice + "\t").getBytes());      //selling price
        out.write((commission + "\t").getBytes());     //realtor commission
        out.write((tax + "\t").getBytes());            //sales tax
        out.write((netPrice + "\t\n").getBytes());     //net price
    }
    out.close(); 
    br.close();
    System.out.println("Net profit/loss:  " + netTotal);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Java, you should try to create an Object model for your application before proceeding. It is difficult to explain the entire approach but perhaps you could start with creating a class diagram for the application.

I'll try to give some hints without being too specific. I want to highlight that the following is just one of the ways to do it and may not be the best approach.

At a high level, think about the operations you want to perform and the data that the operations will work on. In your case, for ex, you have 3 activities - read from file, perform calculations and then output data. Create separate worker classes for these activities. Also think of classes that will store the data. These classes would be useful to pass along the data between worker classes.

Next, design how the classes will communicate with each other to get the job done. For ex, you could have a controller class that manages the 3 activities by collaborating with the other components to get the job done. It could call the file-reader component to get the data from the file, then it would send the data to calculating component to do the calculation and get back results which would then be passed to the writer-component.

Again, this is a simplistic approach but may not be the best solution. As you go along, review and refactor as necessary.